# Gemfile.lock with RubyMotion

Tags: rubymotion

I know that I'm supposed to commit `Gemfile.lock` to source control with Rails.  I also know that I'm not supposed to commit it when developing gems.

Should I commit `Gemfile.lock` to source control when using RubyMotion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

If you're working with other developers, committing the `Gemfile.lock` will ensure that you're all developing against a consistent set of gems - the exact same reason you're meant to commit this in a rails project.

Some examples of people I've found on the internet who've committed their Gemfile.lock:

- https://github.com/daraosn/ardrone-rubymotion-controller
- http://thunderboltlabs.com/posts/using-bundler-with-rubymotion.html
- https://github.com/epicagency/rubymotion-inspect